# String `!23` is replaced with `docker` in command line

Tags: bash

I have a Maven command with the parameter:

```
mvn test -Dcommon_password=!23foo
```

This command is being executed as

```
mvn test -Dcommon_password=dockerfoo
```

I.e. `!23` is being substituted with `docker`.
Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators): `!23` is replaced with the 23rd command in your history.

To avoid this, use single quotes:

```
mvn test '-Dcommon_password=!23foo'
```

Comment: or disable it completely with `set +H`/`set +o histexpand`

Comment: This is a password that can potentially contain all sorts of shell metacharacters.  Properly quoting and escaping as in M. Kitt's answer is better than disabling _just one_ of the possibilities that could occur.  Of course, not having a password in process arguments in the first place would be _better still_.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP in my question I showed a password in a plain text just for simplicity reason. In a real project that argument takes the value from a Jenkins secret credential. So it’s masked and safe.